# "parameter 'self' unfilled" when using decorators, even after instantiating object

Tags: python

I'm using a decorator with parameters to do something with an instance attribute (self.x in this example, if track_bool is true). However when running I get the "parameter 'self' unfilled" error when calling b.do(). From what I understand this error is supposed to appear when calling an instance method before instantiating an object, so I don't understand why it appears in this case when I've used b=B(). Is this something to do with the fact I'm using decorators ? Help please !

Edit: The code does run, but I would like to understand the error so that it doesn't risk breaking anything when running with the rest of my code.

```
# make decorator
def incrementor(track_bool):
    def wrapper(f):
        def wrapped_f(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if track_bool:
                self.x += 1  # do something with self.x
                print('increment')
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_f
    return wrapper


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    @incrementor(track_bool=True)
    def do(self):
        print("this is a function with x=", self.x)


b = B()  # instantiate
b.do()  # call decorated method
```

Here is the image of the error:
[PyCharm IDE message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uhBx.png)

Comment: The code works fine for me - can you replicate your error and update the question?

Comment: Your code works for me. Where do you see the error? Is it coming from your IDE perhaps?

Comment: Yes, so the code runs fine, but my PyCharm IDE puts up the "parameter 'self' unfilled" error on the b.do() line. I'll add a snapshot of it.

Comment: I don't know if I should take it seriously or not... I mainly don't want this to bite me in the butt later on down the line !

Comment: I'm using PyCharm 2021.2 and I don't see this notification.

Comment: I have PyCharm 2021.2.1 pro version. Hopefully this is just some over-zealous checking from the IDE !

Comment: Installing PyCharm 2021.2.1 Community . . .

Comment: Ok, I can see this if I choose: Code/Inspect Code.

Comment: Calling b.do(3) for example, gives me a ```TypeError: do() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```. Funnily enough, if I add a second parameter like ```def do(self, text):``` and then call ```b.do("some text")```, the error message disappears ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is PyCharm being a tiny bit too eager. You should submit a bug report for this because your code is actually working just fine and you don't want to have to go round suppressing all calls to decorated methods.

Here is a work-around. You can change the decorator to not have an explicit `self` parameter:

```py
def incrementor(track_bool):
    def wrapper(f):
        def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
            if track_bool:
                self = args[0]
                self.x += 1  # do something with self.x
                print('increment')
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_f
    return wrapper
```

Note how you can still get hold of `self` because it is guaranteed to be the first element of `args`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer it was really bugging me ! I'll send them a bug report as you suggest.